# USB boot on mid 2010 Intel Mac mini

Tags: mac, macos, usb, startup, mac-mini

I have a mid 2010 Mac mini. I recently did an SSD upgrade in it. I tried using Internet Recovery to reinstall Mac OS X Lion (after which I am planning to upgrade further).

However, the setup never downloads for me saying **The item is not currently available**.

Do I have the choice of USB boot? If not, is there a way to fix the error itself?

Comment: You can boot from USB. However, you'll need a Mac running macOS to create a bootable USB installer.

Comment: Will the boot drive have to be of MacOS Lion only? Or can it be any other supported version?

Comment: Also, how is one suppose to boot into usb? It didnt seem to boot for me at first..

Comment: macOS High Sierra is the last supported release for Mac mini Mid 2010. You should be able to download High Sierra installer from a Mac running it.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372

Comment: thanks, lastly just to confirm, all intel macs have usb boot, right?

Comment: Yes. Intel Macs can boot from USB.

Comment: thanks again, it worked.. please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS High Sierra 10.13 is the last supported release of macOS for Mid 2010 Intel Mac Mini.

- [macOS High Sierra - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP765)

You will need another Mac running macOS to create a USB bootable installer for. Instructions to create a bootable USB media can be found here:

- [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201372)